# Reversing an array [UPDATED], file scanning

Tags: c, arrays, file

The question asked me to scan in an array from a file and then print that array in reverse order.

The idea was that I read up online that in order to reverse an array I would could use a `for` loop and simply print the array backwards rather than actually reversing it. However, I have run into a problem where it just doesn't print anything at all. I used sizeof operator because I was trying to find a way to find out how many elements there are in the array since the amount of elements in file1 can be random.

The code I have so far is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int line[256];
int i, p, k;
    FILE *file1=fopen("f1.txt","r");
    FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    fgets(line,256,file1);
    p=sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);
    k=p-1
    for(i=k;i>=0;i--){
        fprintf(file2,"%d",line[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and try to compile your code.

Comment: You haven't specified a size for your `line` array; what do you expect to happen?  You have other syntax errors too.  Please study how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  (Hint: you're close, but not quite there.)  You should avoid global variables, too — all of `line`, `i`, `p`, and `k` should be local to `main()` in your code. You also have problems with not reading in a loop and not have enough space for more than one line allocated (if that).

Comment: Thanks for responding, you say im close but i am pretty confused as to where to go from here.i edited some of my code to fix some of the errors you pointed out but i am still lost

Comment: Your edit fixes one syntax error but not the other.  There's at least one semantic error (quasi-syntactic error; look at the `fprintf()` statement carefully, or get your compiler to tell you about the error in that line) — ignoring the lack of error checking on the `fopen()` calls.  Then there are the high-level design problems.  They still have to be resolved.

Comment: oh yes fprintf is using a int. I am not sure what the high level design problems are...

Comment: You're going to have to interpret your requirements/specification. You've still not compiled the code you've submitted.  Your code is reading a line of up to 255 characters including newline, plus a terminal null.  Then, regardless of how long the line was, it is printing the single characters stored in `line` as decimal numbers in reverse order, starting with `line[255]` and proceeding to `line[0]`.  You might be better off using `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()`.  For some purposes, your use of `sizeof()` is OK, but probably not this time.  You might want to print the characters with `"%c"`.

Comment: I cant seem to figure out what is wrong. i do not really know how to proceed past where i am right now

Comment: `f1.txt` : is it binary? or text?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is just like this:

```
int main(){
    int line[256];
    int i, p, k;
    FILE *file1=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    fgets(line,256,file1);
    p=sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);
    k=p-1;
    for(i=k;i>=0;i--){
        fprintf(file2,"%d",line[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

file1.txt:

```
987654
32
1
```

---

I think you want to reverse the string of each line. And you want to know where is wrong in your code. I'll show you where is wrong in your code.

**See what happen when you use `sizeof`.**

```
int main(){
    int line[256];
    int i, p, k;
    FILE *file1=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    fgets(line,256,file1);
    p=sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0]);
    printf("sizeof(line[0]) = %d\n", sizeof(line[0]));
    printf("sizeof(line) = %d\n", sizeof(line));
    printf("p = %d\n",p);
}
```

output:

```
sizeof(line[0]) = 4
sizeof(line) = 1024
p = 256
```

It seems sizeof return just memory space size which variable points.
If so, you shouldn't use `sizeof`, because you want length of string.

**Use `strlen`**

Short answer is to use `strlen`.

```
int main(){
    char line[256];//<---changed here
    int i, p, k;
    FILE *file1=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    fgets(line,256,file1);
    p=strlen(line);
    printf("p = %d\n",p);
}
```

output:

```
p = 7 //<---length of "987654\n"
```

I'll stop here.
But This is the first entry point of what wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int line[256];
    int i, p, k;
    FILE *file1=fopen("f1.txt","r");
    FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");

    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<256 && fscanf(file1, "%d", &p)==1;++i){
        line[k++] = p;
    }
    for(i=k-1;i>=0;--i){
        fprintf(file2, "%d\n", line[i]);
    }
    fclose(file1);fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After a few modifications to your program, this will read from file1 and reverse all the strings in file1 and put them in file2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char line[256];
int i, p, k;

FILE *file1=fopen("f1.txt","r");
FILE *file2=fopen("file2.txt","w");

 char *pos;
 while(fgets(line,256,file1)!= NULL){
    //p=sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])//always 256, sizeof line[0] = 1;
  if ((pos=strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL) //remember fgets returns a \n if its end of line
        *pos = '\0';
  else if((pos = strchr(line,'\0')) !=NULL)
        *pos =  '\0';
  pos = pos-1;
  while(pos >=line){
        fprintf(file2,"%c",*pos);
        pos = pos-1;
  }

    fprintf(file2,"\n");

}
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(char *i=pos-1;pos >= line;pos--){` : UB. {pos | &line[0] <= pos <= &line[256]}. and See previous his question.

Comment: changed to a while loop.